# How to make intersection "line vs box" without penetration many objects?

Tags: java, swing, 2d, game-physics, java-2d

can someone give me idea how can i make intersection only first box when the line is stretched to mouse cursor? Im trying to make something like "raycasting" but don't know how to stop the line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CzpW.png

I tried line-line intersection but don't know how to find proper wall of the box

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Java has a [java.awt.Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) class where you can define a rectangle.  This class has a contains method and an intersect method where you can determine if a line is contained ion a rectangle or intersects a rectangle.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thank you so much Mr Gilbert. Problem solved :)